# Italic font in chinese

Tags: ctex

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\begin{document}
    \textit{这是中文斜体, 文字是楷体, (括号是斜体的)}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

In Chinese, we seldom use true italic font. As shown in the above example, italic font in Chinese are displayed as "Kaishu", a widely used Chinese font. However, punctuations, like `(`, are displayed as true italic font. This is very weird since all chinese are not truely italic.  Is there any way to display all puncturations in upright fonts?

Comment: Since Chinese doesn't really have italics, is there a reason why you need to use `\textit` with Chinese text?

Comment: @bonk  I don't need it expilicitly.  However,  italics are implicitly defined in some environments, for example, the default style for theorem environment in amsthm package.

Comment: That is an ASCII `(` do you need that in input or can you use U+FF08 `（` (FullWidth Left Parenthesis) which would come from the CJK fonts?

Comment: Are you using `pdflatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it's an ASCII `(`. We usually use english punctuations when writing academic papers.

Comment: @egreg  I'm using xelatex.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

As said in ctex.pdf, CTEX bundle defines not only some Chinese fontset, but also some font switch commands (`\songti`, `\heiti`, `\fangsong`, `\kaishu`) (note there is no `\fangsong` in ubuntu fontset). So all you need is `\kaishu`:

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textit{这是中文斜体, 文字是楷体, (括号是斜体的)}.
  \item {\kaishu 这是中文斜体, 文字是楷体, (括号是斜体的).}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I suspect that you find it easier to read the ctex.pdf documentation than I do:-) I'll leave my answer up as it explains why those characters act differently but I think this is likely to be the answer that should be accepted

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I suspect the second version using U+FF0C, U+FF08, U+FF09 and U+FF0E punctuation is most correct but I do not know Chinese input conventions.

```
\documentclass{ctexart}
\begin{document}

\section*{Original}

\textit{这是中文斜体, 文字是楷体, (括号是斜体的)}.

\section*{Chinese Punctuation}

\textit{这是中文斜体，文字是楷体，（括号是斜体的）}.

\section*{No Italic}
{\let\itshape\upshape % globally or added to environments using Chinese

\textit{这是中文斜体, 文字是楷体, (括号是斜体的)}.

}
\end{document}
```